# If a character has a mishap during a term, and must leave the career, how quickly can he re-enter the same career, and will he retain his rank?

Tags: character-creation, traveller, mongoose-traveller-2

During a career you may have a mishap and be forced out of that career. Can you immediately reapply to the same career? If this is the case at what rank do you enter the career, same as when you left it?

In my RP mind it seems that you should not be able to just reenter at the same rank after what might have been a dishonourable discharge. So for instance, if you're a O2 in the Marine when you get the following mishap:

> You are tormented by or quarrel with an officer or fellow marine. Gain
> that character as a Rival as he drives you out of the service.

It seems odd if your able to just reenter at O2 level and continue your officers career. I am curious to know both what is common practice among GM's and if there is anything in the rules about it (that I have overlooked).

Comment: I don't know if it makes a difference, but is this Mongoose Traveller 1 or 2?

Comment: 2016 edition og the game

Comment: Historical note: In MGT1, you couldn't re-enter a career after leaving it due to a failed survival roll unless the specific mishap you suffered permitted you to do so; In CT and MegaTraveller, failing a survival roll meant you failed to survive, rendering the question moot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot easily reapply for a career once you left it, except when drafted ("Einberufung") into it by happening to roll the matching number after you selected "Drafting into" as Career step.

From my rulebook (translated from German)

> **Qualification**: You need to make this roll to get into the career [...] You cannot return to a Career once you have left it. The only exception to this is when you are drafted into it [...]

If that happened in my session, I would rule that you are kicked out of one division, but another has no qualms with you, so they take you anyway. You lose the advancement in the year of your failed survival role (as you would anyway), but can otherwise stay on the rank you had the year before.

Comment: Looked at the character generator for MGT2 on rpgsuit.com, and it also prevents you from reentering after a mishap. (Just as a note: The character generator in my mind has a very Beta-quality, and not worth the $40 I paid for it, so even though I refer to it I do not recommend buying it at this time.)